# Please allow question/answer "source" to cookie or save

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

Please allow us to cookie / save the source of our questions and answers with the following drop down box:

[image]

Because we use teams so much I am constantly having to change this box based on the team I need to look at.  If this were cookied it would save me from having to change this all the time.